# Understanding steps in a proof.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, proof-explanation

A part of the proof is given below:

> [image]

**My questions are:**

1. I do not understand why "Since $f'(x) = 0$, we can find $y_{x} > 0$ such that we have both $[x,y_{x}] \subseteq (a,b)$ ".

   Could anyone explain this step for me please?
2. Why the set $\mathcal{B}$ is a vitali cover of $E$? Where is the required condition on the $\varepsilon $ i.e. $\ell[x,y_{x}] < \varepsilon $ for every $\varepsilon >0.$

   Could anyone explain this for me, please?

Comment: Your included proof has a minor typo. We have $y_x>x$ and not $y_x>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question : just apply definition of $f'(x)$.

Second question: Vitali cover means for  every $\epsilon >0$ there exists a  member of the cover with length less than  $\epsilon$. [ Not that every member of the cover has length less than  $\epsilon$ ]. Since $[x,y]$ is included in this cover for every $y$ with $x <y <y_x$ this property is obviously satisfied.